# JPA UUID Generation

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I am just starting out with JPA and I have what may well be a stupid question, but if it is, it means that there is something fairly fundamental about JPA!  Please forgive me if this is a stupid question, but I have not been able to find the answer anywhere.

I want to auto-generate UUIDs for the primary keys of my tables and I have read a lot about how to do this and read all the warnings about the ID not being available until the object is persisted and how this can affect the equals and hashCode methods, but I have come up with a solution that I can't see a problem with, but I am suspicious of because I haven't been able to find any reference to the method anywhere on the Web!

The method is simple:

1. Implement an @PrePersist method that sets the ID field if it is null.
2. Implement a getter for the ID that calls the @PrePersist method before returning the value.
3. Implement hashCode and equals so that they use the getter to get the ID rather than accessing the field directly.

In my, possibly simplistic view of things, this would appear to solve all the issues, but I must be missing something as otherwise surely there would be examples of using this method everywhere!

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with this solution:

- If you getter will call the `@PrePersist` callback, the Id will be set at unexpected times, without anyone noticing. Changing the object in a getter is a good example of side effects you should avoid.
- If your application is responsible for assigning the ID before persisting, you will run into situations, where the `@PrePersist` callback is activated, but the entity is not persisted (an adverse TX rollback for example).
- These isssues will make you unable to reliably distinguish between persisted and unpersisted objects.

Comment: The second point doesn't apply as the application cannot assign the ID.  Once an instance has an ID, it has it for life.  This is why an ID is only generated if the instance doesn't already have one.  If I needed to know whether an instance was in the database or not I would use PostPersist and PostLoad to set a flag wouldn't I?  As for the first point, since the PrePersist method will only generate an ID if the instance doesn't have one, either previously assigned by another call to that method or loaded from the database, why is it an issue?  I am obviously not getting something here.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier for you to use a separate static method (in a separate class), which will perform the initialiation of the id of the Entity for you.

Simply use `UUID.random()` to provide a unique String for your    POJO/Entity, and then merge it with PersistenceContext so that the id is reflected in the database.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1) Artem is correct in that the first thing to do is to get yourself a static UUID generator. Personally I use [JUG](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JugHome) as follows:

```
private static TimeBasedGenerator uuidGen = Generators.timeBasedGenerator(EthernetAddress.fromInterface());

public static String next() {
    String uuid = uuidGen.generate().toString();
    return uuid;
}
```

2) Your `@PrePersist` method will fail someday when you create a new object and serialize it over a web service (e.g. REST/SOAP) because you will serialize it before the transaction is complete (otherwise you get the dreaded Hibernate lazy init error).  So you often need to set the Id before your save.  I use the getter side effect for this.

3) Putting the side effect in your getter is fine as along as you put your JPA annotations on the field and not the property accessor.

4) Your hash code cannot soley rely on the Id because there will be times when Hibernate will deserialize your object and add it to a HashMap before it is initialized.  It's rare but it happened to me tonight which is how I found your question.  So my hashcode is now:

```
final public int hashCode() {
    return id == null ? getClass().hashCode() : id.hashCode();
}
```

As of now this is working well and passing all unit/integration tests.